# laravel mix compile assets is very slow in 92 percent

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-mix

i use laravel mix to compile my react app

and when i run `npm run production` to compile in product mode it's very slow in 92% and take 50 seconds or more

```
  mix.setPublicPath('../public')
 .js('resources/js/management/management.js', 'js')
 .js('resources/js/pusher.js', 'js')

 .js('resources/js/ecommerce/ecommerce.js', 'js')
 .js('resources/js/cipol/cipol.js', 'js')
 .js('resources/js/common/map.js', 'js')
 .js('resources/js/common/cart.js', 'js')
 .js('resources/js/common/cartbutton.js', 'js')
 .js('resources/js/common/cartmodal.js', 'js')

 .js('resources/js/common/trending.js', 'js')
 .js('resources/js/common/editorcomponent.js', 'js').
 options({
    processCssUrls: false,
    autoprefixer: false

 })
 .react();

 mix.webpackConfig({
  output: {
    chunkFilename:(pathData) => {
        return '/management.cipol.net/js/chunks/[name]2.js';
    }
 },

resolve: {
    fallback: { // not present by default
        "crypto": false,
        "stream": false,
        "fs": false,
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core":false,
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons":false,
        "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome":false
    }
},
});
```

and my laravel mix version is ^6.0.49

Comment: not sure if 50 seconds for a production build is slow. It really depends on your code and dependencies  but to me it does sound like a normal build time for a medium sized application.